# Angular animation in steps instead of continuous movement

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I would like to use Angular Animations to animate folding and unfolding of a card. I have the animation saved as a spritesheet containing 8 steps and I need to change background-position-x to switch between these 8 images, but not contiously but in steps. Similarly like CSS steps() timing function.

I have tried  following:

```js
transition(":enter", [
  animate("0ms 42ms", style({ "background-position-x": "-600px" })),
  animate("0ms 42ms", style({ "background-position-x": "-1200px" })),
  animate("0ms 42ms", style({ "background-position-x": "-1800px" })),
  animate("0ms 42ms", style({ "background-position-x": "-2400px" })),
  animate("0ms 42ms", style({ "background-position-x": "-3000px" })),
  animate("0ms 42ms", style({ "background-position-x": "-3600px" })),
  animate("0ms 42ms", style({ "background-position-x": "-4200px" })),
  animate("0ms 42ms", style({ "background-position-x": "-4800px" })),
]),
transition(":leave", [
  animate("0ms 42ms", style({ "background-position-x": "-4200px" })),
  animate("0ms 42ms", style({ "background-position-x": "-3600px" })),
  animate("0ms 42ms", style({ "background-position-x": "-3000px" })),
  animate("0ms 42ms", style({ "background-position-x": "-2400px" })),
  animate("0ms 42ms", style({ "background-position-x": "-1800px" })),
  animate("0ms 42ms", style({ "background-position-x": "-1200px" })),
  animate("0ms 42ms", style({ "background-position-x": "-600px" })),
  animate("0ms 42ms", style({ "background-position-x": "0" })),
])
```

however it still animates the background position continuously instead of steps. When I put there 1ms instead of 0ms it kinda works, but the movement is sometimes visible.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz? not sure what look you are aiming at

Comment: yeah sure, i will send it tomorrow (its half past midnight here)

in the meantime I came up with a workaround, which is to set animation duration to 0.001ms